# Intermediate Files formed during compilation of DART code

Tags: dart, compiler-construction

I want to see intermediate files which are formed during compilation for DART code, what command should I run in cmd?

Example: For hello.c file, I can run `gcc -Wall --verbose --save-temps -o first-exec hello.c` to see intermediate files which will be formed like hello.s, hello.s, hello.o.

I want to see similar assembly code files formed during DART compilation? Any command through which I can see it ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the native Dart compiler creates any files. It's handled entirely in-memory. The web-compilers are different because they actually do create `.js` files.

The VM definitely do not create assembler files, its built-in assembler writes directly to memory. There is not a separate assembler, like `cpp`'s `as` or `gas`, which is run on an intermediate result.

Even the AOT native compilation does not have that kind of intermediate step.

You can choose to compile to a `jit-snapshot` or `kernel` file using, e.g., `dart compile kernel`. That shows you the intermediate Dart format.